# Meaning of "be brought low"

Tags: meaning, idioms, verbs, adjectives

Context ([New York Times](http://www.nytimes.com/2011/08/21/us/21bcbart.html?_r=1&ref=technology)),

> The episode has been a sobering lesson in how even an agency that carries some 350,000 passengers over 104 miles of track every workday can **be brought low** by a seemingly ragtag group of activists who identify themselves by pseudonyms like Lamaline_5mg.

In [Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cold+cash), I found this entry,

> be brought low (old-fashioned) to lose your wealth or your high position in society

But I'm wondering if we can just simply interpret this idiom literally?  Please see these two entries in [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bring?show=0&t=1314376188),

> bring: (4) : to cause to come into a particular state or condition.
>
> low: 11: unfavorable, disparaging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Brought low* indicates that once it was high up, and something caused it to lose its high position.  In this case, the power of a prestigious cell phone communications provider was compromised by a "seemingly ragtag group of activists", which is a "sobering lesson".

So *X was brought low by Y* means *though X previously had much power/ability, Y compromised/destroyed it to the point that X has very little ability*.

Comment: -1 "answers should contain references"

Answer (score 1):

It comes from bring down, as you might "bring down" a government - so somebody who has lost power or authority has been "brought down" (in BE) or "brought-low" (AE)

Answer (score -1):

I've read it (in fiction, mostly) to mean that an individual has been embarrassed or shamed, or that something has happened to bring about a low mood. I can easily see how this would be an extension of the above provided definition.

Comment: Welcome, @Kettle! We usually look for answers that have supporting material. Do you have a reference for that meaning that you can [edit](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/189400/edit) into your answer?